# Building both amd64 and arm64 with GitHub workflows from different files

Tags: docker, github-actions

What is the correct way to setup GitHub workflow for the multi-platform (amd64+arm64) Docker image build? I have two different docker files, one for each platform (see [MapLibre/Martin](https://github.com/maplibre/martin/blob/main/.github/workflows/docker.yml) project), and I tried to do it with a matrix configuring both platform and file params, but for some reason it publishes `linux/amd64` image with the `linux/arm64` metadata, and another image has `unknown/unknown`.

```yaml
jobs:
  docker:
    name: Build ${{ matrix.platform }} docker image
    strategy:
      fail-fast: true
      matrix:
        include:
          - platform: linux/amd64
            file: Dockerfile
          - platform: linux/arm64
            file: arm64.Dockerfile
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker meta
        id: docker_meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ghcr.io/maplibre/martin

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v2.1.0
        with:
          platforms: linux/arm64,linux/amd64

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.5.0
        with:
          install: true
          platforms: ${{ matrix.platform }}

      - name: Build the Docker image
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          file: ${{ matrix.file }}
          push: false
          load: true
          tags: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.labels }}
          platforms: ${{ matrix.platform }}

      - name: Login to GitHub Docker registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' && !github.event.pull_request.head.repo.fork }}
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Push the Docker image
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' && github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          file: ${{ matrix.file }}
          push: true
          load: false
          tags: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.labels }}
          platforms: ${{ matrix.platform }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `strategy: matrix: ...` to do a multi-platform build. It will be much easier if you can integrate your two Dockerfiles into a single Dockerfile. Add `--platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` to the first `FROM ...` line of your Dockerfile.

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM rust:alpine as builder
```

You should try to settle on the same set of base images to use for both your arm and amd builds. If you can't, then it gets a bit more involved.

Within your build step use an array of platforms:

```
    - name: Build Docker images
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
        platforms:
           - linux/amd64
           - linux/arm64
```

You'll end up with something like this:

```
jobs:
  docker:
    name: Build docker images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

      - name: Checkout sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Docker meta
        id: docker_meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@v4
        with:
          images: ghcr.io/maplibre/martin

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2.5.0

      - name: Login to GitHub Docker registry
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' && !github.event.pull_request.head.repo.fork }}
        with:
          registry: ghcr.io
          username: ${{ github.actor }}
          password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Push the Docker image
        if: ${{ github.actor != 'dependabot[bot]' && github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.docker_meta.outputs.labels }}
          platforms: 
             - linux/arm64
             - linux/amd64
```

Comment: Thank you @will-holtz!  What if we do have to use two different dockerfiles?  (we might be able to parametrize the dockerfile and have some conditional if statements, but not yet certain). What options will we have? Thx!  P.S. See https://github.com/maplibre/martin/pull/613

Comment: You have to deal with the docker manifests directly, as described here: https://www.docker.com/blog/multi-arch-build-and-images-the-simple-way/. You can find a GitHub Action that will help you do this here: https://github.com/Noelware/docker-manifest-action

Comment: there must still be something wrong - "docker exporter does not currently support exporting manifest lists" - https://github.com/maplibre/martin/actions/runs/4560165725/jobs/8044858699